# How does declaring variables in swi prolog work?

Tags: variables, prolog, swi-prolog

Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm still new to Prolog's syntax, Im just asking how would one declare/instantiate and manipulate a variable X (if possible) and be able to write/print it out similar to other languages. For example:

```
int x = 5;
print(x);
```

or even swapping variables

```
int x = 5, y = 10, z;
z = y;
x = z;
y = x;
```

Is it possible to implement these in prolog? If so, how? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

You are not the first person to ask this exact question. Even searching around on Stackoverflow would have been easier. By now I suspect there is a CompSci professor out there just trolling their students with this question.

Your example looks like C or a C-like language. Other very popular languages do not require declarations, for example Python. Declaring variables is an artifact of early compiled languages. This is a very broad topic that belongs to a university-level lecture on compiler design, programming language design and so on.

You "swap variables" when your variables are handles to registers in the processor or memory locations. Prolog is on a very different level, to the point that I feel like saying "unask the question" despite not being too wise.

So, let's start again: **what are you trying to achieve by swapping variables**?

If you want to print a 5, write:

```
?- X = 5.
X = 5.
```

or maybe:

```
?- write(5).
5
true.
```

and so on and so forth. Long story short, there is more to this question than meets the eye, but I am not convinced this is the right place to ask it.

Comment: @LucasMaine This has nothing to do with intelligence. This is about information. You are lacking information, so I am giving you the obvious advice, "get more information". You can ask all you want but this involves strangers on the internet: they are sometimes helpful but usually they are just strangers on the internet. So, start by reading on your own, it is much easier.